# Retrieved data displayed in forms cannot be submitted correctly in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I retrieve data from a database and show them to their corresponding forms in template. Then, when I'm trying to update a field, these forms do not submit the retrieved data and as a result forms are not validated.

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

**views.py**

```
def results(request):

    context = RequestContext(request)
    myid = request.GET.get('id', '')
    diag_option = 0
    print "my id", myid
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_demographics = DemographicForm(request.POST or None, prefix="demo")

        if my_demographics.is_valid():
            my_demographics_object = my_demographics.save()

    else:

        patient = Demographic.objects.get(patient_id = myid)

        my_demographics = DemographicForm(instance=form_data)      

    return render_to_response('input.html', {'frm':my_demographics}, context)
```

**template results.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="input">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="tab-pane" id="mytab">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="1">
                <!--<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="demographics">-->
                <div class="container"> {%crispy frm%}</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class DemographicForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DemographicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper=FormHelper(self)
        self.fields['date_of_birth'].widget = widgets.AdminDateWidget()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'national_health_care_pat_id',
            'patient_hospital_file_number',
            'patient_id',
            'given_name',
            'surname',
            'date_of_birth',

            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
                Submit('cancel', "Cancel")
            ),

        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True

    class Meta:
        model = Demographic
        exclude = []
```

Does the way I retrieve data matter?

I use the above code in another template to find a patient.

```
patient = Demographic.objects.select_for_update().filter(patient_id = myid)
```

Comment: Can you please cut down your code to the minimum here: which of the many forms in that view is causing the problem? Does it still happen with a single form? And you should probably post the code for the form itself as well.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes you are right! Done!

Comment: The form doesnt have any action, so unless you post it to the same url you're on it won't work.

Comment: @limelights Yes, I post it to the same url I am.

Comment: You don't need this mumbo jumbo with `serialize` and `json.loads` to pass initial data to the form - since you're using a `ModelForm`, just pass your model instance as `instance` ie `DemographicForm(instance=patient)` (as documented here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thank you for your advice! Still, this does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, working on @brunodesthuilliers solution!

The problem is that I have to pass the `instance=patient` even after the `request.POST`, in order the django understands to deal data as an update.

**views.py**

```
def results(request):

    context = RequestContext(request)
    myid = request.GET.get('id', '')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        with transaction.atomic():
            patient = Demographic.objects.get(patient_id=myid)

        my_demographics = DemographicForm(request.POST or None, instance=patient)

        if my_demographics.is_valid():
            my_demographics_object = my_demographics.save()

    else:
        with transaction.atomic():
            print "HERE ELSE"
            patient = Demographic.objects.get(patient_id=myid)

        my_demographics = DemographicForm(instance=patient)

    return render_to_response('input.html', {'frm':my_demographics}, context)
```